# Extrair numpy arrays de um dicionário iterativamente

Tags: python, dicionário, numpy

Tenho um dicionário do seguinte tipo:

```
data = {'neuron4':Numpy array, 'stim':Numpy array, 'neuron3':Numpy array, 'neuron2':Numpy array, 'neuron1':Numpy array}
```

Eu tentei fazer algo do tipo

```py
for k,v in data.items():
   ...
```

Porém não sei bem como associar a novas variáveis (com os mesmos nomes das keys do dicionário) os arrays (values).
Sei que posso fazer

```py
neuron4 = data['neuron4']
```

Mas queria evitar escrever um por um.

Minha intenção é criar essas variáveis, tirar as médias data['neuron4'].mean(axis=0) de cada uma e depois visualizá-las num gráfico.

Muito Obrigado!!

P.S.: Como o usuário jfaccioni comentou abaixo, não preciso criar variáveis. Posso usar diretamente os valores do dict.

Comment: A ideia de um dicionário é justamente associar valores a nomes (chaves), que você pode trabalhar como sendo "variáveis" dentro de uma mesma estrutura. Não há nada que você possa fazer com a variável `neuron4` da expressão `neuron4 = data['neuron4']` que você já não pudesse fazer acessando `data['neuron4']` - e melhor ainda, iterativamente.

Comment: Entendi... então você me aconselha a usar diretamente `data['neuron4']` em plt.plot como algo do tipo `plt.plot(data['stim'], data['neuron4'].mean(axis=0))`? Com somente 4 variáveis(chaves) é fácil, mas o que você me indicaria fazer se tivesse 100 delas? Escrever uma por uma não seria apropriado.

Comment: Depende do que/como você quer plotar os dados. Escrever chaves uma a uma seria trabalhoso, mas o ponto que levantei é que escrever *variáveis* uma a uma também daria o mesmo trabalho. Por outro lado, se você sempre quiser plotar `data['stim']` como valores de X e `data[neuron<algum_número>]` como os valores de Y, faz sentido escrever `xs = data['stim']`, iterar sobre os pares chaves-valor do dicionário e plotar cada valor como y: `for k, v in data.items():` `if k != 'stim':` `plt.plot(xs, v.mean(axis=0))`. Porém isso não ficou claro na sua pergunta.

Comment: Funcionou!! Muito obrigado. (Editei a pergunta com essa sua observação.)